# Sharing a common Android SDK on both Android Studio and Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am on Windows 8. I have some questions regarding Android SDK:

1. Can both IDEs share a common Android SDK?
2. Will there be any issues in updating IDEs?

Comment: This link has more details
http://envyandroid.com/archives/1027/eclipse-android-studio-use-one-android-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Generally, yes, it's safe to share a common Android SDK for both Eclipse and Android Studio. Updating IDEs won't affect the SDK at all.

Take note when updating/deleting packages in Android SDK Manager: you might use some packages (e.g. specific API version) in a particular IDE (past example: Android "L" Developer Preview in Android Studio). Updating/deleting them may break the project that use them, and it might be difficult to fix the issue. However, for already-stable APIs like Android KitKat (API 19) and below, there won't be any issue when updating them.

Additional note: Android project created in either Android Studio or Eclipse is not really compatible to each other due to different project structure and technology. Therefor, it's better to always use the same IDE for projects that are created in it. If you want to test both IDEs on same project, it's better to [export the project from Eclipse](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html), instead of from Android Studio as it's easier.